# Can I run clang static analyser on only a subset of the files in a project?

Tags: clang-static-analyzer

I'm looking to run clang's static analyser on files that are part of a larger project. I don't want to compile the entire project, only a subset of files. Is that at all possible?

Comment: Are you looking to analyse say 10 out of 1,000 files, or ignore 20 out of 1,000 files? And why?

Comment: @gnasher It'a reserch project. I have a dataset of files from different projects. and I want to apply static analysis. I don't have all the files from each project. There are several thousand files from hundred of projects.